# MySQL fast searching through word index

Tags: python, mysql

I'm indexing thousands of documents. I'm using python + mysql.

I have generated a list of indexes, words, from the documents and I'm storing them in MySQL database in the following format.

```
word_index | document_id
danger | 1
los angeles | 2
paint | 1
paint | 2
paint | 3
paint | 4
monday | 1
monday | 2
monday | 3
monday | 4
```

There are about 500 million rows in the database.

So when I query about "monday" for example, the result will return around 50,000 rows to process. So, it is very very slow.

What can I do to speed up the process? How does search engines handle their massive index database?

Any tips or hints are welcome.

Comment: Have you created an index on the `word_index` column?

Comment: @isedev, I have. However, the index is around 30GB big while my machine has only 8GB RAM. Another problem is it's returning 50,000 rows while I might actually not need all.

Comment: @isedev maybe i should make it documents_id to be comma separated? That's why my index size will be reduced.???